# How to routerlink *ngfor case method

Tags: angular, ngfor, routerlink

I have faced compiling error on router link *ngFor method

HTML

```
<mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="'push'">
   <mat-nav-list>
      <a *ngFor="let mnu of menus" mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/mnu']">{{mnu}}<\a>
   <\mat-nav-list>
<\mat-sidenav>
```

Main.JS

```
Menu:  string[] = ['Login', 'Data Table', 'Google Map', 'Input Form', 'Web View', 'Image Viewers', 'Video Viewers', 'Video Viewers',
   'PDF Viewers', 'Chat Vox' ];
```

```
Error
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'mnu'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'mnu'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)`enter code here`
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
```

Comment: The error is quite clear. All your links try to link to the same route '/mnu' which doesn't exist. You probably want `[routerLink]="['/' + mnu]"`

Comment: Note: your code would be much clearer if you used real words, respected the naming conventions, and used the plural form for arrays: names your array `menus`, and name your ngFor variable `menu`. Finally, having spaces and uppercase letters in paths is not a good idea.

Comment: HI JB - Thanks for your quick reply.  
login.component.html
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Login'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Login'

Comment: If "cannot match any routes", then show us your routes definition.

Comment: 'Login' and 'login' are different strings. One starts with an uppercase `L`, the other starts with a lowercase `l`.

Comment: HI JB, How to create a custom pipe to visible for 'Data Table' and 'data-table.component.html'